# Изменить параметр на дату AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день , как можно сделать чтобы параметр отправлял нужную дату.

```
var CupApp = angular.module('CupApp', []);
CupApp.controller('CupCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  var number = $filter('number');

  function comparator(cup) {
    return number(cup.Addon_2, 0) != 2;
  }
  $scope.comparator = comparator;
    $http.get('http://UT_base/hs/buffnew/total?' , {params: { start : 20170828 , finish : 20170903 } }).success(function(data) {
      $scope.cups = data;
    });
  });
```

В данный момент мне приходится в ручную подставлять дату в параметры `Start` и `Finish` , а хотелось бы автоматически. Нужны параметры : `start` Начало года - 
 `finish` конец года / И идентичные для месяца и недели

Comment: автоматически откуда?

Comment: Автоматически текущий месяц  и текущая неделя

Comment: `var now = new Date();`, `now.getFullYear()+(now.getMonth()+1)+now.getDay()` так? только нули добавить к месяцам и дням

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**moment.js** попробуйте.

Пример как использовать:

```
var CupApp = angular.module('CupApp', []);
CupApp.controller('CupCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
var number = $filter('number');

function comparator(cup) {
   return number(cup.Addon_2, 0) != 2;
}
$scope.comparator = comparator;
    $http.get('http://UT_base/hs/buffnew/total?' , { 
            params: { 
                 start : moment(/*специфичные параметры даты*/).format("YYYYMMDD"), 
                 finish : moment(/*специфичные параметры даты*/).format("YYYYMMDD") 
            } 
    })
    .success(function(data) {
         $scope.cups = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: А какого типа должны быть /*специфичные параметры даты*/ ?

Comment: Если я ничего там не указываю - то подтягивается сегодняшний день. А как сделать начало/конец месяца и недели? в мануале moment.js не могу найти связанных с этим данных

Comment: Все , нашел. params: { 
                 start : moment().startOf('month').format("YYYYMMDD"), 
                 finish : moment().endOf('month').format("YYYYMMDD")

Comment: @heymukki, я бы Вам рекомендовал отказаться от ``$http`` и перейти на использование ``$resource``. Это более высокоуровневый сервис, позволяющий быстрее создавать обращение к бэкенду